# how to solve sequence jumping issue in odoo 14?

Tags: odoo

In sale , I applied different sequence for sale quote and sale order.

If sale quote is SQ001 , sale order generated as SO001 after confirming the order.

If sale quote is SQ002, sale order generated as SO003 after confirming the order. #sequence is jumping.

Please someone help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try changing sequence implementation to "No gap". Path is Settings -> Technical (you need debug mode) -> Sequences -> find sequence and set implementation to "No gap". After this, you will no longer have gap with future orders.

[image]